# How to use action_name in a conditional validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm not sure if this is the best way. But I am trying to add validations to my user model, based on if they are editing their account or creating it.

Obviously if I don't define the conditional validation, you'll never be able to log in as the presence isn't there for say :city in the sign_up however is on account_update.

What I have is:

```
validates :about, presence:true, if: :edit_account

def edit_account
 action_name == 'edit'
end
```

ive tried several others but I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `action_name'
```

Is there a better solution to this, and if it's not how do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
validates :about, presence: true, :on => :update
```

[more info in Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on)

Comment: such a noob mistake by me. How would this work if I were to create a grouping out of it? For several fields that all needs to be :on => :update? 
Found it out: 
  with_options on: :update do |update|
    validates :about, presence:true
  end

Comment: Simple use validates :about,:city, :address, presence: true, :on => :update

Answer (score 0):

You can add an [option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on) on: :update to run the validation only when a record is updated.

```
validates :about, presence: true, on: :update
```